# Return type of assignment operators in wrapper class?

Tags: c++, oop, properties

I came up with the following code to implement C#-style properties in C++. It's basically a wrapper class around `typename T`, with user-defined get/set functions:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct property
{
    property(std::function<T(void)> getter, std::function<void(const T&)> setter)
        : get(getter), set(setter) { }

    property(std::function<T(void)> _getter)
        : get(_getter), set([](const T&) { throw std::exception(); }) { }

    property<T>& operator=(const T& value) { set(value); return *this; } // w i h   o   s   h r ? 
    T operator=(const T& value) { set(value); return get(); }            //  h c   t   u e   e e   
    operator T() { return get(); }

    property<T>& operator=(property<T>& value) { set(value); return *this; };   //...
    T operator=(property<T>& value) { set(value); return get(); };              //...

    property<T>& operator=(property<T>&) = delete;

    // arithmetic / assignment
#define OP(__OP__) \
    T operator __OP__(const T& rhs) { return get() __OP__ rhs; } \
    T operator __OP__##= (const T& rhs) { set(get() __OP__ rhs); return get(); }              //...
    //property<T>& operator __OP__##= (const T& rhs) { set(get() __OP__ rhs); return *this; } //...
    OP(+); OP(-); OP(*); OP(/); OP(%); OP(^); OP(&); OP(|);
#undef OP

    // bit shift
#define OP(__OP__) \
    T operator __OP__(int rhs) { return get() __OP__ rhs; } \
    property<T>& operator __OP__##= (int rhs) { set(get() __OP__ rhs); return *this; }
    OP(<<); OP(>>);
#undef OP

    // comparison / logic
#define OP(__OP__) bool operator __OP__(const T& rhs) { return get() __OP__ rhs;}
    OP(<); OP(>); OP(==); OP(!=); OP(<=); OP(>=); OP(&&); OP(||);
#undef OP

    // inc/dec
#define OP(__OP__) \
    property<T>& operator __OP__##__OP__() { set(get() __OP__ 1); return *this; } \
    T operator __OP__##__OP__(int) { T value = get(); operator __OP__##__OP__(); return value; }
    OP(+); OP(-);
#undef OP

    T operator ~() { return ~get(); }
    bool operator !() { return !get(); }

private:
    std::function<T(void)> get;
    std::function<void(const T&)> set;
};

struct test
{ 
    property<int> a = property<int>([&]()
    {
        return x/10;
    }, 
    [&](int value) 
    {
        x = value*10;
    });

    property<int> b = property<int>([&]()
    {
        return y+10;
    }, 
    [&](int value) 
    {
        y = value-10;
    });

private:
    int x, y;
};

using namespace std;
void main()
{
    test x;

    x.a = 5;
    x.a = x.a + 15;
    x.a *= 5;
    x.b = x.a;
    x.b += x.a / 10;

    cout << "property a=" << dec << x.a << endl; // should be 100
    cout << "property b=" << dec << x.b << endl; // should be 110
}
```

My main question here is, should the assignment operators return a `T` or a `property<T>&`? Returning a reference seems nicer, yet I want to avoid accidentally reassigning the entire class (including the get/set functions), although I believe overloading `operator=(property<T>&)` and deleting the copy constructor sufficiently guards against this.
Anyway, both seem to produce the same results, so is there any difference between the two? Which would you prefer and why?

Edit, related question: in the case where a `set` function is not defined, is there some way to detect assignment at compile time, instead of throwing a run-time exception?

Comment: shouldn't you rather post this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @m.s., thanks, I didn't know about the codereview site. Should I repost there or is there some way to move the question over?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, returning by copy will work okay, but there are some perverse situations where it won't.  Consider the following:

```
struct A { 
  A(int i) : i_{i} {} 
  int i_; 

  A operator=(A const& A) { i_ = a.i_; return *this; }
};
```

And then try this:

```
A a1{1};
A a2{2};
A a3{3};
(a3 = a2) = a1; // What is the value of a3::i_?
```

Returning by copy means that the `a3 = a2` assignment generates a temporary that is reassigned to equal `a1`.   In other words `a3::i_ == 2` after the assignment.  If you return by reference, `a3::i_ == 1`.